# Java plugin JVM parameters

Tags: java, debian, sun

we are using Debian Squeeze with iceweasel and sun java6

```
java-common        0.40          Base of all Java packages
sun-java6-bin      6.22-1        Sun Java(TM) Runtime Environment (JRE) 6
sun-java6-jre      6.22-1        Sun Java(TM) Runtime Environment (JRE) 6
sun-java6-plugin   6.22-1        The Java(TM) Plug-in, Java SE 6
iceweasel          3.5.15-1      Web browser based on Firefox
```

we need to limit the amount of memory java uses when an applet is loaded from the web.
By default we see it is using arround 400MB which is a very high value since it is running in kiosk terminals with 512-1024MB of RAM.

in the folder of the user running iceweasel there is a  .java/deployment folder with a deployment.properties file:

```
#deployment.properties
#Fri Feb 11 08:07:23 UTC 2011
deployment.version=6.0
deployment.capture.mime.types=true
deployment.browser.path=/usr/bin/firefox
#Java Deployment jre's
#Fri Feb 11 08:07:23 UTC 2011
deployment.javaws.jre.0.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.0.platform=1.6
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osname=Linux
deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/bin/java
deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.6.0_22
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osarch=i386
deployment.javaws.jre.0.location=http\://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
deployment.javaws.jre.0.enabled=true
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=
```

This file is created if down't exists when an applet is run. I set 
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Xmx128m but don't seem to follow it

I had been tweaking with the parameters and some of them seem to be honored -Xms and -Xmn but not sure which is the parameter I must set to limit the total amount of memory java can use.
I always get:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
3007 user      20   0  **379m**  34m 8184 S  0.7  3.6   0:04.84 java
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall the only way to set the Xmx for java plugin is via the java control panel. It has got default value there that overrides the other settings.